# Ordering content with in columns in Bootstrap Grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple bootstrap grid set for two columns ( content left and right ) that break down everything to one column in mobile and tablet.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Left Column</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Right Column</div>
</div>
```

The problem is I'm trying to order stuff INSIDE each column after both columns break down to one column. In other words: I have a two paragraphs that are divided between the two columns, when the page is on desk-top, the first part of the paragraph is in column one, while the other is horizontally aligned with it in column two, so when the grid breaks, part two goes underneath everything else in part one and not the first part of the paragraph.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 1</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 2</p>
        <p>other stuff</p> 
        <p>other stuff</p>   
        <p>other stuff</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

So to put it simply, PARAGRAPH 1 PART 2 needs to go underneath PARAGRAPH 1 PART ONE when only one column remains.

I have looked into bootstrap push and pull, and that won't work in this instance. I otherwise have not been able to find any documentation regarding this specific issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that `.col-md-x` set x columns for devices >= 940px, when the width is below that, the grill will show vertically, so the second col-md-6 (part-two) goes underneath of the first one(part-one) whit all its content, then having said that.

You can use:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>other stuff1</p>
        <p>other stuff1</p>
        <p>other stuff1</p>
        <p>other stuff1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">        
        <p>other stuff2</p> 
        <p>other stuff2</p>   
        <p>other stuff2</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

or the same thing but more structured

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>other stuff1</p>
        <p>other stuff1</p>
        <p>other stuff1</p>
        <p>other stuff1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">        
        <p>other stuff2</p> 
        <p>other stuff2</p>   
        <p>other stuff2</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

BUT I really recommend you use: [CSS3 Multiple Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: Great simple straight forward answer that worked like a charm. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm really glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve it. But I suggest using more columns, and then adding the push-pull classes as needed. Code below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>other stuff</p> 
        <p>other stuff</p>   
        <p>other stuff</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

note: I added extra classes (col-xs-12 in some extra places I think) just to make it a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden-xs, hidden-sm  and visible-xs, visible-sm to achieve what you want.

Basically, you add hidden-xs and hidden-sm to PARAGRAPH 1 PART 2 in the other column and then add the same thing in the original column with visible-xs and visible-sm. Here's what I mean:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>PARAGRAPH 1 PART 1</p>
        <p class="visible-xs visible-sm">PARAGRAPH 1 PART 2</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">PARAGRAPH 1 PART 2</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
        <p>other stuff</p>
    </div>
</div>
```